# git default commit message include files reset in pre-commit hook

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, commit-message

In my workflow I want to make some changes in file and keep them in my local machine. For this purpose I have written a `pre-commit` hook to reset those files before any commit.

The problem is that the default message:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   FileToBeCommited1
#   FileToBeCommited1
#   FileAlreadyResetByPre-comitHook
```

has a list of files that will be committed. Fore some reason it always contain the names of the files that I have already reset in my hooks.
Its not really a big problem, but I would like it to be resolved if possible. Also I don't want to write `prepare-commit-msg` hook to write the full message myself.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to [ignore local changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/6309) for those files using [`git update-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index):

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- file1
git update-index --skip-worktree -- file2
git update-index --skip-worktree -- file3
```

That way, no need for a hook resetting those.
And the commit message remains clean.

Comment: thanks, but am not looking for alternative, cause this method has its own down sides, like rebase or merge overwrites silently. In pre-hook method I have to consciously stage and re-apply... I like that approach better

Comment: @Suryavanshi to my knownledge, those skipped files are *not* overwritten silently (as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/27027732/6309)

Comment: In my personal experience, they did get overwritten during `git pull --rebase`

Comment: @Suryavanshi What git version are you using?

Comment: @Suryavanshi Could you test it with git 2.7.4 or git 2.8?

Comment: Will update, if I get to it. Currently 1.9.1 is the latest in ubuntu repo

Comment: @Suryavanshi I have documented how to upgrade before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34469473/6309. git 2.8 is available in that ppa since... an hour ago ;)